# Combining array of array with another array in PHP using array_combine

Tags: php, arrays

I'm playing around with array functions to get a better understanding.

Below I have three arrays:

```
$cardNumber = array(2, 4, 5, 8, 9);
$playerName = array('Julian', 'Brad', 'Chloe', 'Laura', 'Paul');
$playerWins = array(4, 5, 1, 2, 6);
```

I am trying to achieve the following array structure:

```
array (size=5)
  2 => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => string 'Julian' (length=6)
      1 => int 4
  4 => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => string 'Brad' (length=4)
      1 => int 5
  5 => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => string 'Chloe' (length=5)
      1 => int 1
  8 => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => string 'Laura' (length=5)
      1 => int 2
  9 => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => string 'Paul' (length=4)
      1 => int 6
```

I decided to combine `$playerName` and `$playerWins` with `array_combine()`, and then combine the resulting array with `$cardNumber`, which does not yield the output I expect. Am I understanding `array_combine()` incorrectly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `array_map` with *null* as a callback and the two data arrays to give you the array structure that you want.  Then combine that with the array for the keys using `array_combine`:

```
$result = array_combine($cardNumber, array_map(null, $playerName, $playerWins));
```

For illustration:

```
$result = array_map(null, $playerName, $playerWins);
```

Yields:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Julian
            [1] => 4
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Brad
            [1] => 5
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Chloe
            [1] => 1
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => Laura
            [1] => 2
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => Paul
            [1] => 6
        )
)
```

Then combine to get the keys:

```
$result = array_combine($cardNumber, $result);
```

Yields:

```
Array
(
    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Julian
            [1] => 4
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => Brad
            [1] => 5
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [0] => Chloe
            [1] => 1
        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [0] => Laura
            [1] => 2
        )

    [9] => Array
        (
            [0] => Paul
            [1] => 6
        )

)
```